# Как представить свойство C# с приватным методом доступа к записи в UML

Tags: c#, uml

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше представить свойство с приватным set в UML диаграмме классов?

```
private long clock;
public long Clock
{
    get { return clock;}
    private set { clock = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Поле по сути будет представлять таймер, который будет обрабатываться формой.
Само свойство изменяется в классе и использование {readOnly} в UML нотации не желательно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760539/17025310

Comment: Спасибо большое!